# If $a<b<c<d$ , then the roots of the equation, $(x-a)(x-c)+2(x-b)(x-d)=0$ are real and distinct.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How do I prove the above problem?

I tried finding discriminant, It wasn’t very useful as it didn’t yield any useful conclusion.

Comment: Did you try studying the sign of $(x-a)(x-c)+2(x-b)(x-d)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x)=(x-a)(x-c)+2(x-b)(x-d)=0$$

$$\iff g(x)=(x-a)(x-c)=-2(x-b)(x-d)=h(x)$$

and

- $g(x)$ is a parabola concave up which intercepts $x$ axis at $x=a$ and
  $x=c$
- $h(x)$ is a parabola concave down which intercepts $x$ axis at $x=b$ and
  $x=d$

thus by IVT $2$ distinct real roots exist for $f(x)=0$.

Comment: You have a great solution but is there any way to do this using the discriminant method the OP used...It leads us to this inequality $(a-c)^2+(2b-2d)^2+4(a+c)(b+d)>8ac+8bd$ and if this is true then the claim is true...But can be prove this?